# How can I pass an array through a Helm template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using Helm v3.

The issue is that I've a template which gets an input value from a values.yaml file.

I've a parameter that looks as follows:

```
{{ if .Values.school.students}}
students: {{ .Values.school.students}}
{{ end }}
```

Now, the actual value of students looks something like this:

```
students: ["student1", "student2", "student3"]
```

I need students to be an array but currently it gets passed as a string.

I read a few answers online where it was mentioned that we can use "--set" flag but I'm not clear.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through `.Values.school.students` using [range](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures#looping-with-the-range-action)

```yaml
{{- if .Values.school.students }}
  students: -|
  {{- range .Values.school.students }}
    - {{ . | quote }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, invalid type: got "string", expected "array"

Comment: @pep8 can you give more context? What command are you running? Can you share your whole manifest file?

Comment: Your solution worked with some minor changes. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: How can I make this work if I want to add more values to the `students` array? Let us say that I already have `students: ["student1"]` and I want to add `["student2", "student3"]`